# Optional Parameters in MAIN() for JAVA

Tags: java, program-entry-point, optional-parameters

Is it possible to implement optional parameters for a Java program?

I tried searching this up, but all that came up was for overloading methods in Java, not specifically the main().

What I'm trying to do is run a Java program with an optional flag, i.e.:

```
~ java Program textfile.txt [optional flag]
```

where Program must run with a supplied text file, but not necessarily optional flag.

Comment: That's what the `args` parameter in `main` is for...

Comment: As in an OPTIONAL parameter, the program must run with a supplied textfile, but it can run without the optional flag. I'm not sure how to implement that in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All arguments are in args parameter of main.   You must implement the logic for processing it.

If you are feeling lazy and want to try some libraries, have look at [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli//) library.